# Is 天的数月 the correct way to say "days of the month"?

Tags: translation

Is Tiān de shù yuè (天的数月) the correct way to state "days of the month"? I am looking for a term that will encompass all of the days of the month. This will be the heading for a paragraph that lists each day of the month. In English, the words "these are the" is implied in this phrase, so I suppose "(these are the) days of the month" is the term I am looking for. This will then be followed by Chūyī (初一) 1st, Chūèr (初二) 2nd, etc... listing them as the days of the month. I am looking for an expression similar to "Days of the week" are Monday, Tuesday, etc through Sunday. "Days of the month" are 1st through 28th, 30th or 31st depending on the month. I am looking for the Chinese term for "days of the month"

Comment: No. It is not correct. Can you provide more context?

Comment: I am looking for a term that means "days of the month" like one would says "days of the week" or, another way to put it "(these are the) days of the month".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of everyone who took the time to answer this question, I was able to find the correct term I was looking for. The answer is Hào (号), which means "day of the month". I especially want to thank @Tyr and @monalisa for the help in getting me in the right direction to find this answer.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for "今天几号"? (Like for a week, we say "今天周几")

Comment: @Shaw, your phrase is a question. It isn't what I was looking for, but it is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

"一個月中的幾天" might be the right translation

---

**update**

Now I understand your question!

If you want to list every days of the month, the answer might be

- 這個月有 (這些日子), 初一, 初二, 初三 ...
- 這個月有 (這些日子), 一日, 二日, 三日 ...
- 這個月有 (這些日子), 一號, 二號, 三號 ...

They are all right, but I prefer the second one or the third one

For example, if you want to list every days in February, it can be "二月有, 一號, 二號, 三號 ... 二十八號"

Comment: This phrase translates to "a few days in a month".

Comment: @Tyr You are getting me very close to what I am looking for. Using your phrase, I came upon a single word 号 Hào. Google translate says one of it meanings is "day of the month". Is this correct?

Comment: @Walter Yes! you got it!! :D

Comment: and usually "初一初二" means days in Lunar(Chinese) calendar

Comment: Thank you, @Tyr, I am doing a comparison of ancient calendars, like Norse, Persian, Roman, Japanese, etc... most of which are lunar. So, I'm extremely grateful for yours, and everyones help.

Answer (score 1):

No it is incorrect. I assume you want to say '(The number of）days of the month'.

It should be:

这个（**This** as in the current one or one that was mentioned in previous context) or 本 (**This** as in the current one) 月 (month) 的 ('s) 天 (day) 数 (number).

天的数月 makes no sense to me as a native speaker. It would be if I say **day's number month** in English.

Comment: I am looking for a term that encompasses all of the days of the month. In English, with the term "days of the month" there is an implied "these are the". so, what I am looking for, is a Chinese term that means "these are the days of the month"

Comment: Still unsure what your question is. There is no term that encompasses all the days of a month. If you'd make a couple of complete sentences, it may help.

Comment: @monalisa Have heard of the terms "days of the week" and "days of the month" before, in English? "Days of the week" are Monday, Tuesday, etc through Sunday. "Days of the month" are 1st through 28th, 30th or 31st depending on the month. I am looking for the Chinese term for "days of the month"

Comment: @Walter My previous comment still holds. There is no one term that encompasses all the days of a month. I asked for complete sentences because translation simply doesn't work like what you might think it should. A noun (phrase) may not have a ready equivalent noun (phrase) in another language. A good translation is not necessarily word-for-word. With context, a good translator will be able to express the same idea in the most natural way in the target language. I think this is what people looking for a translation need to be aware of.

Comment: @monalisa Ok. I now understand what you are requesting. The full sentence for this should be: "These are all of the days of the month." or "This is a list of all the days of the month

Comment: @Walter In that case I guess I would say 一个月里(within a month)有(have/there are)这些(these)天(days).

Answer (score 0):

No.

days of the month should be translated to: "某月几日"

例如, 3th April means  四月三日,  or 四月初三